# No matching function call to template function

Tags: c++, templates, function-calls

A template function I have written has the following signature:

```
template<class IteratorT>
auto average(IteratorT& begin, IteratorT& end) -> decltype(*begin)
```

I thought that this would work fine, but apparently it doesn't. I call the function by passing in pointers to the beginning and end of an array:

```
int integers[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
auto average = sigma::average(&integers[0], &integers[8]);
```

But clang tells me that it cannot find a matching function:

> error: no matching function for call to '`average`'

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the expression`&integers[0]` returns an *rvalue* which cannot be bound to non-const reference parameters of `average` template function.

So the  solution is to make the parameters non-reference (removed `&`):

```
template<class IteratorT>
auto average(IteratorT begin, IteratorT end) -> decltype(*begin)
```

Then call it as (although it is not that important, but `&integers[8]` seems to invoke undefined behavior, pedantically speaking):

```
auto average = sigma::average(integers, integers + 8);
```

But why do you need such a function template to begin with? You could use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) as:

```
#include <algorithm> //must include this

auto average = std::accumulate(integers, integers + 8, 0)/8;
```

Comment: Well, `average` internally uses `std::accumulate` and devices by `end - begin`. Just a convenience function, since my application calculates averages *a lot*.