# Calling a template function problems "No matching function for call" arguments: iterators, object function

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am learning for an exam in Object oriented course, and I have an ex about STL, including library algorithm, iterators, etc etc. I am trying to send to a function iterators, and object function, and it doesn't work. The compiler is saying "No matching function for call"

I have search here solutions of others, and I fix some of the issues (r-values type) and still, got no idea what is the problem. None of the solutions I found solve it.

Tthis is the specific function:

```
template <class IT1, class IT2, class FUNC>
void swapElementsIf(IT1& begin1, IT1& end1, IT2& begin2, IT2& end2, FUNC f) {
    if ((begin1 == end1) || (begin2 == end2))
        throw EmptyExp();
    while (begin1 != end1 && begin2 != end2) {
        if (f(*begin1, *begin2))
            std::swap(*begin1, *begin2);
        begin1++;
        begin2++;
    }
    if (((begin1 == end1) && (begin2 != end2)) || ((begin1 != end1) && (begin2 == end2)))
        throw NotSameSizeExp();
}
```

and I call it from the main, like that:

```
swapElementsIf(v1.begin(),v1.end(),l1.begin(),l1.end(),std::less<double>());
```

Comment: take iterator by value instead of by refrence.

Comment: Well thank you. i did find a subject like that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351463/no-matching-function-call-to-template-function

Comment: and i tried that on my code, here's i put my professor solution code... tsk tsk tsk...

Comment: @JesperJuhl well, just wanted to be nice, and not throw on people a question, no one owe me anything.

Comment: @halfer Thank you sir, i will take that in mind for the future. I am sorry that my english isn't perfect, i will try to pay more attention :)

Comment: No worries @Eran. We're fine with people not having great English - it is quite an unfairness that people who only speak English don't have to learn a new language. As long as people make an effort, that's fine by us. Install an English spell-checker into your browser `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer We have people working on that. How's your Esperanto?

Comment: @user4581301: sadly it is as rusty as my Latin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector::begin()` returns a temporary object (r-value), temporaries cannot be passed to functions taking references (l-values).

Always look at the full compiler error output as it normally contains hints with modern compilers. E.g. clang prints:

```
<source>:26:5: error: no matching function for call to 'swapElementsIf'

    swapElementsIf(v1.begin(),v1.end(),l1.begin(),l1.end(),std::less<double>());    

    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

<source>:9:6: note: candidate function [with IT1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, IT2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, FUNC = std::less<double>] not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument

void swapElementsIf(IT1& begin1, IT1& end1, IT2& begin2, IT2& end2, FUNC f) {

     ^
```

Change your function to take iterators by value:

```
void swapElementsIf(IT1 begin1, IT1 end1, IT2 begin2, IT2 end2, FUNC f)
```

Iterators are usually basically just a pointer so are cheap to copy so there is no benefit to using references anyway.